# Adding video clip in Libre Impress on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: libreoffice

When I add MP4 video clip in Libre Impress on Ubuntu 16.04, save and close the file, next time when opened the same file the video clip disappeared? Any solutions?

Comment: I can't reproduce it, it works for me. Can you explain in detail how you inserted the video? I chose insert -> audio/video. Do you have kind of unusual characters in the videos filename? Does it work with other videos?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It  is just a normal mp4 file produced by simple screen recorder mp4 file with english name without space having  .mp4 extension. Yes, I follow same steps as you did to insert the video. insert>audio/video then select the file.

Comment: Ya. I tried using ODP extension it works but not for PPTX extension though.

Comment: Oh this is an important detail. I tried it, and Libreoffice warned me that some contents may not be stored in .pptx files. Did you not get the warning? It seems that this feature is not supported (yet). I guess the problem is here that LibreOffice wants to store a copy of the video in the presentation file, which does not work with this kind of file. I wonder why it does not store a reference (the video path) instead.